# Display select result

Tags: php, mysql

I tried to build a query to select data from the database, which I can use for the future login form to determine if a user is activated or not.

So in my attempt at this, I did the following:

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","steven","PASSWORD!","leercentrum");

echo("This Works");

$query = "SELECT activated FROM users WHERE username = 'steven' ";
$result = mysql_query($con, $query);
print_var($result);
```

The query works on my database via SQL Workbench.

I also attached a screenshot of my Mysql database (Table users).

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uef3g.jpg]

The only thing I want is create an boolean-returning function to determine if a user is activated (return value `1`) or not activated (return value `0`).

Comment: `mysql_query($con, $query)` you didn't RT\*M on this or on `mysql_connect("localhost","steven","PASSWORD!","leercentrum")`

Comment: Every time you use [the `mysql_`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)
 database extension in new code
 **[a Kitten is strangled somewhere in the world](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-zCT6jizimfI/UjJ5UTb_BeI/AAAAAAAACgg/AS6XCd6aNdg/s1600/luna_getting_strangled.jpg)** it is deprecated and has been for years and is gone for ever in PHP7.
If you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli` database extensions.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: all that is mysqli_ syntax, not mysql_ - `mysql_connect()` does not use 4 arguments, not for the 4th one anyway

Comment: @chris85 In that case can we throw in some PDO syntax for good measure

Comment: `print_var($result);` ? Do we have a new PHP print function as well?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

Comment: @RiggsFolly nope http://php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=print_var&scope=quickref ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting as a community wiki.

As I outlined in comments....... you can read those.

Here is your fixed code:

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","steven","PASSWORD!","leercentrum");

echo("This Works");

$query = "SELECT activated FROM users WHERE username = 'steven' ";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
// print_var($result); Not a core PHP function.
```

RTMs:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Since I suspect you were used to using mysql_ and thought the same was the same, well...... it isn't.

Btw, `print_var()` isn't a core PHP function.

See for yourself http://php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=print_var&scope=quickref

- `print_r()` is. http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php

Why you want to print that, is unknown.

You need to fetch over successful results.

Read the manual http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: Thanx everyone for the comments I just have used 
print_r ($result); and now I got as result:  This Worksmysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 1 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 1 [type] => 0 ).
I expected that would be just 1 because in the field activated the value is 1 nothing more. Or do I see it wrong ?